# How to make Atom split screen "stay" even after closing the last tab on a pane?

Tags: atom-editor

In Sublime Text 3, when you initiate split screen, there can be empty containers for each pane. However, in Atom, when you close the last one, it goes away. Are there any hacks for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to install a separate package. Once you set `core.destroyEmptyPanes` to `false` in your `config.cson` empty panes will no longer be destroyed. Alternatively, edit the setting graphically:

1. Open your Settings View (e.g. by typing `settings-view:open` in the Command Palette).
2. In the Core tab, remove the checkbox in front of `Remove Empty Panes`.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer. Here's the package for it: https://atom.io/packages/pane-layout-plus